# Validating pyspark dataframe columns with the same data quality rules

Tags: python, pyspark

I created a dummy pyspark dataframe.
[image]

I am trying to enforce the following rules:

`rules = [{"column": "last_name", "value": "NA", "name": "Percentage of 'NA' Values in Last Name"},{"column": "first_name", "value": "NA", "name": "Percentage of 'NA' Values in First Name"} ]`

I would like to have one dictionary key for the NA rule since applies to both first and last name rather than having to list the same rule twice.

`rules = [{"columns": ["last_name", "first_name"], "value": "NA", "name": "Percentage of 'NA' Values in Last Name and First Name"},{"column": "country", "value": "USA", "name": "Percentage of 'USA' Values in Country"} ]`

Below is what I have done so far. Any good tips on a way forward on obtaining the same results but using the second set of rules?

```
percentages = []

for rule in rules:
    column = rule["column"]
    value = rule["value"]
    name = rule["name"]
    count = df.filter(col(column) == value).count()
    total_count = df.count()
    percentage = (count / total_count) * 100
    percentages.append({"name": name, "percentage": percentage})
for result in percentages:
    print("{}: {:.2f}%".format(result["name"], result["percentage"]))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cleanest way is altering your rules to:

```
rules = [{"columns": ["last_name", "first_name"], "value": "NA", "name": 
"Percentage of 'NA' Values in Last Name and First Name"},
{"columns": ["country"], "value": "USA", "name": "Percentage of 'USA' Values in Country"}]
```

Then, you can alter your code to use this standard format:

```
percentages = []

for rule in rules:
    columns = rule["columns"]
    value = rule["value"]
    name = rule["name"]
    for column in columns:
        count = df.filter(col(column) == value).count()
        total_count = df.count()
        percentage = (count / total_count) * 100
        percentages.append({"name": name, "percentage": percentage})
for result in percentages:
    print("{}: {:.2f}%".format(result["name"], result["percentage"]))
```

You can make further adjustments to also add the names in a list of names and print accordingly.

If you want to stick to your format, you could check:

```
for rule in rules:
    if columns in rule:
        #process as multiple columns
    else: #(column in rule)
        #process as one column
```

Comment: I ended up expanding on the rules and had to differentiate my loop approach and could no longer use just columns; but column for single column rule and columns for multiple columns rules.